# Tables are displayed incorrectly

Tags: bug

I don't know why but when I opened [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/282559/filter-based-on-object-field-in-typescript) I saw that tables are displayed incorrectly

[image]

so I wanted to suggest changes but when I [clicked to Edit](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/282559/edit) I saw that now tables are displayed correctly

[image]

Comment: Might be one for [meta.se] - do you know if it affects other SE sites?

Comment: @TobySpeight No I don't if this problem affects other SE sites, so I decided to post only in this site

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known problem, also on other sites. The preview will parse correctly even without newlines around the tables, but the post itself will not. See [revision 4](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/282559/revisions):

```
Data in List 1 :

|id|itemName|quantity|
|:-:|:-:|:-:|
|J254|corn|154|
|I465|wheat|169|
|O25845|strawberry|200|
|J365|corn|205|


Data in List 1 filtered :

|id|itemName|quantity|
|:-:|:-:|:-:|
|J254|corn|154|
```

Data in List 1 :

| id | itemName | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| J254 | corn | 154 |
| I465 | wheat | 169 |
| O25845 | strawberry | 200 |
| J365 | corn | 205 |

Data in List 1 filtered :

| id | itemName | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| J254 | corn | 154 |

See [Rendered view requires blank line before (and after) tables, but preview accepts both](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/404376/1014587) on MSO.

Comment: Thank you! The question on MSO was asked 2 years ago... Is there any chance that this issue will be fixed?)

Comment: @EzioMercer You'd have to ask there, I don't know.